# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout

Tags: android, xml

I want to change title bar text and background color by programmatically. That is why , I have used the following code :

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity{
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.customtitlebar);
        TextView customTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customtitlebar);
        customTitleText.setText("Whatever you want in title");
         }
}
```

My customtitlebar.xml is as following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@color/titletextcolor">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="25px" 
        android:layout_height="25px"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"> 
    </ImageView>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/customtitlebar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="" 
        android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@color/titlebackgroundcolor" 
        android:padding="3px" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But when I want to run the project , I am getting this exception :

```
03-09 17:21:52.181: E/ActivityThread(15403): RuntimeExceptionjava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.asif.gmaillogin/com.asif.gmaillogin.SplashScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout
```

How can I solve this exception ? Please help me .

Answer (score -1):

See at line 19 on xml file. TextView `android:text=""` attr is empty, if you want make it without text remove this attr

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/customtitlebar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@color/titlebackgroundcolor" 
    android:padding="3px" />
```

Comment: @Sagor Ahmed Post your logcat

Comment: 03-09 17:49:31.925: E/ActivityThread(17935): RuntimeExceptionjava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.asif.gmaillogin/com.asif.gmaillogin.SplashScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout

Comment: @Sagor Ahmed Try to change your Activity theme. Don't use appCompat theme and instead AppCompatActivity use Activity

Comment: What theme should I use ?

Comment: @Sagor Ahmed `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"`

Answer (score -1):

This line must be the problem

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
```

You must call `requestWindowFeature()` before `super` as well as `setContentView()`.

Your code will be like -

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.customtitlebar);
        TextView customTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customtitlebar);
        customTitleText.setText("Whatever you want in title");
    }
}
```

P/s, There are requirement to user `getWindow().setFeatureInt();` method. Refer this [SO link](http://getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,%20R.layout.customtitlebar);) to learn more.